# C# Reflection, Reflection.TargetException, when Invoke ToString(IFormatProvider)

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, invoke, propertyinfo

I'm trying to get a float property with reflection and use its ToString(IFormatProvider) method to set another property, type of string.
I get "Reflection.TargetException, Object does not match target type" error. I will put some code below to explain it:

```
public class myForm : Form
{
        public float myFloat { get; set; } = 2.78f;
        public string myString { get; set; } = "127";
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get "myFloat" property of this instance of Form.
            PropertyInfo myfloat_property = this.GetType().GetProperty("myFloat");
            //Get ToString(IFormatProvider) method of the "myFloat" property.
            MethodInfo to_string = myfloat_property.PropertyType.GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(IFormatProvider) });
            //Set "myString" property. Where i get the exception.
            myString = (string)to_string.Invoke(myfloat_property, new object[] { CultureInfo.InvariantCulture });
        }
}
```

I think i'm missing something easy to see. But i can't see it now, can you show me?

Thanks all.

Comment: You have to pass an instance. You can't just pass in a PropertyInfo. You'd have to call GetValue passing in the class instance (the form) and then use the result of that as the instance passed to ToString

Comment: I knew that it is easy to see and i couldn't see it. Thank you for showing it to me. The problem is, PropertyInfo myfloat_property is not the myFloat property so using myfloat_property to invoke to_string MethodInfo causes exception. It is just a "Reflection" of myFloat property not itself. I think i have a long road to master programming. Thanks, i have a road to walk.

Comment: It would look something like this. Note it's untested or else I'd post an answer (plus I'm sure this is a duplicate anyways): `myString = (string)to_string.Invoke(myfloat_property.GetValue(this), new object [] { CultureInfo.InvariantCulture });` This does beg the question as to why you need to do this with reflection as you have direct access to the properties of the form from within the button click handler.

Comment: I tested and edited the question for the ones like me. Thank you for your answer. I think i earned a new vision how to/should use Reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error when you pass the wrong `this` object to the `Invoke()` method, i.e. an object having a type different from the type for which the invoked method was declared.

In your case, it's because you are passing a `PropertyInfo` object, `myfloat_property`, when in fact you should be passing the value of the property itself. For example:

```
public class myForm : Form
{
    public float myFloat { get; set; } = 2.78f;
    public string myString { get; set; } = "127";
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get "myFloat" property of this instance of Form.
        PropertyInfo myfloat_property = this.GetType().GetProperty("myFloat");
        //Get ToString(IFormatProvider) method of the "myFloat" property.
        MethodInfo to_string = myfloat_property.PropertyType.GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(IFormatProvider) });
        //Set "myString" property. Where i get the exception.
        myString = (string)to_string.Invoke(myfloat_property.GetValue(this), new object[] { CultureInfo.InvariantCulture });
    }
}
```

Now, that said, there are a couple of things unclear in your question. The above code would fix the exception. But it hardly seems like the best way to achieve the final result. For example, you already have access to the property itself, so rather than using the `PropertyInfo` object, you could just use the property directly:

```
public class myForm : Form
{
    public float myFloat { get; set; } = 2.78f;
    public string myString { get; set; } = "127";
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get ToString(IFormatProvider) method of the "myFloat" property.
        MethodInfo to_string = myFloat.GetType().GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(IFormatProvider) });
        //Set "myString" property. Where i get the exception.
        myString = (string)to_string.Invoke(myFloat, new object[] { CultureInfo.InvariantCulture });
    }
}
```

But even that seems overly complicated. After all, not only is the property accessible, the `ToString()` method is as well. So your method could in fact look like this:

```
public class myForm : Form
{
    public float myFloat { get; set; } = 2.78f;
    public string myString { get; set; } = "127";
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myString = myFloat.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

No reflection needed at all. And no exceptions. :)

Comment: I will not use it like this. I needed this at something a lot different than that. I just simplified the subject.